# Wrapping assignments in parantheses returns the output of that assignment in console

Tags: r, variable-assignment

I was not aware that if you wrap an assignment in parentheses, the value of that assignment will be printed out in the console. See below; what's the reason for this behavior?

```r
a <- 1
b = 2
assign("c", 3)

(a <- 1)
#> [1] 1
(b = 2)
#> [1] 2
(assign("c", 3))
#> [1] 3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: In the old days it was common to see Examples in R help pages where this was used to obviate the need to repeat the naked typing of the variable name on the LHS of assignments. It's really in service of the REPL of the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an explanation about parenthesis and brace: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Paren.html

> ##### Description
>
> Open parenthesis, (, and open brace, {, are .Primitive functions in R.
>
> Effectively, ( is semantically equivalent to the identity function(x)
> x, whereas { is slightly more interesting, see examples.
>
> ##### Usage
>
> ( ... )
>
> { ... }
>
> ##### Value
>
> For (, the result of evaluating the argument. This has visibility set,
> so will auto-print if used at top-level.
>
> For {, the result of the last expression evaluated. This has the
> visibility of the last evaluation.

##### Examples

```r
f <- get("(")
e <- expression(3 + 2 * 4)
identical(f(e), e)
#> [1] TRUE

do <- get("{")
do(x <- 3, y <- 2*x-3, 6-x-y); x; y
#> [1] 0
#> [1] 3
#> [1] 3

## note the differences
(2+3)
#> [1] 5
{2+3; 4+5}
#> [1] 9
(invisible(2+3))
#> [1] 5
{invisible(2+3)}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is by design.  It's not easy to find it in the documentation, but somewhere there's an explanation that  `(something_with_output)` invokes the 'print' command.

FWIW I find it useful when using closures whose code includes `return(invisible(stuff))`  .

Comment: Thank you, Carl. I found the documentation and posted an answer.