Why do people use parentheses surrounding functions and assignments in R?
Lately I've seen several of these instances:
(NCORES <- nb_cores())

Or:
(ldsc <- with(df_beta, snp_ldsc(ld, ld_size = nrow(map_ldref),
                                chi2 = (beta / beta_se)^2,
                                sample_size = n_eff,
                                ncores = NCORES)))

Why do people use outer parenthesis?

If you include the parentheses, it will print the result to the console, even if you also assign the result to a variable. So it's good for debugging

Parenthesis is used to both assign and print the output of a function.

Someone please post an answer rather than answering in comments ...

I'm likely wrong, but also causes eval of an intermediate calculated value being fed into another function. Again, I'm likely wrong

Try it. Although you are right, it is not really a different thing. f = \(x) x + 1; f(i = 1); f((i = 1))

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75609366/wrapping-assignments-in-parantheses-returns-the-output-of-that-assignment-in-con

Wrapping R code in parenthesis like this (NCORES <- nb_cores()) ensures that the output of the function nb_cores() is both assigned to the variable NCORES and also printed to the R console.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75609366/wrapping-assignments-in-parantheses-returns-the-output-of-that-assignment-in-con
